# need to unserialize data from database field, to replace with its plain text

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

For some reason, I stored an input field as serialized data into a table field and now need to convert all data from serialized data, to plain text.

I have about 2000 records I need to unserialize and then update it with the plain text version.

I have tried a few different things and I am still unsuccessful.

Any suggestions for how I could accomplish updating the serialized values with their values unserialized into their respective row in the table.

Comment: extract, loop, unserialise, replace

Comment: I tried to loop thru and place it within the value="" of an input field, and do a submit, and loop thru the post values, but it submits the values as an array, even though I printed them within value="" via a foreach loop

Comment: You have to write code to do this. You cannot deserialize in an SQL command.

Comment: Brad: Just do an Select on the database for all the values. Iterate over the results. For each result set line deserialize the value in there, and do an SQL update to update the line in the database with the deserialized value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back up your database first, then something like this should work:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `value` FROM `table`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $newdata = unserialize($row['value']);

    mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `value` = '{$newdata}' WHERE `id` = '{$id}' LIMIT 1");

    if(mysql_affected_rows() <= 0)
    {
        print_r("Update failed on ID {$id}! \n");
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll have to modify this as per your needs (table structure, serializing method, etc).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach($volunteers as $r): ?>
  <?php
  print "UPDATE data SET monday = trim('";
  if(unserialize($r->monday) && unserialize($r->monday) != "b:0;" && unserialize($r->monday) != "PM" && unserialize($r->monday) != "AM") {
    foreach(unserialize($r->monday) as $slot):
      print $slot.' ';
    endforeach;
  }
  print "') WHERE id = ".$r->id.";<br />"; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Just copied the output and ran in Sequel Pro (ss http://cl.ly/56AG)